# How can I implement links within a page, while using Client-side routing?

Tags: html, client-side, single-page-application, crossroadsjs

I'm working on an SPA, using crossroads.js for the client-side routing. Everything is working perfectly, with one exception.

I have one page within this SPA that is quite large, and I'd like to be able to use internal links, to provide a table of contents at the top. In the past, I've done something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#Introduction">Introduction</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Chap1">Chapter 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Chap2">Chapter 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Chap3">Chapter 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

These would link to elements within the same page with the corresponding ID.

However, now that I'm using client-side routing, this doesn't seem work work as well. The page that this I'm using this on has a URL like:

```
http://myserver.com/#/Books/12/Full
```

Clicking one of the links above does move the page to the correct location on screen, but it changes the URL to:

```
http://myserver.com/#Chap2
```

Is there a standard way of handling internal links in an SPA, while preserving the URL?

Comment: Do you work with jQuery?

Comment: Yes. That's a good idea. I'll play around with adding a click handler, and use jQuery to navigate to the correct spot. Thanks!

Comment: I'll make you a Fiddle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/PfRvt/)**</kbd>

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li data-rel="div1">DIV 1</li>
    <li data-rel="div2">DIV 2</li>
    <li data-rel="div3">DIV 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="div1">


</div>

<div id="div2">


</div>

<div id="div3">


</div>


$(function() {
  $('nav ul li').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).data('rel')).offset().top }, 900); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change quite a bit to get it working with my project, but since you got me pointed in the right direction, I accepted your answer. I'll add another answer showing how I modified it.

Comment: You're welcome ;) P.S. I don't know your code this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

@mdesdev got me pointed in the right direction, but here's what ultimately wound up working for me:

Using an SPA, the page in question is loaded after the document is loading, so I couldn't get using the jQuery document ready function to add the click handler to work. Instead, I created the following function:

```
function scrollToInternal(target) {
  // #MyContent is the div that needs to be scrolled
  $('#MyContent').scrollTop($(target).position().top);
};
```

Then in my markup, I called this function with the onclick attribute:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="scrollToInternal('#Introduction');return false">Introduction</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="scrollToInternal('#Chap1');return false">Chapter 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="scrollToInternal('#Chap2');return false">Chapter 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="scrollToInternal('#Chap3');return false">Chapter 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Not as elegant a solution as mdesdev's, but it's working.